# Как в phpstorm открыть файл в кодировке windows-1251?

Tags: phpstorm

В проекте перемешаны файлы в разных кодировках. Как бы я не менял настройки, phpstorm открывает любой файл в кодировке UTF-8

[image: Настройки кодировки]

Comment: в правом верхнем углу нажмите на reader mode