# PHPStorm: Открывает файл в UTF-8 вместо windows-1251

Tags: кодировка, phpstorm, utf-8, windows-1251

У меня проект в UTF-8. Но есть каталог в windows-1251. Настройки следующие:

```
Setting | Editor | File Encodings
Global Encoding: UTF-8
Project Encoding: UTF-8
Patch                 Encoding
...\public            windows-1251
...\public\file.php   windows-1251
```

*Специально пробовал указать файл, но не помогает.*

Файл \public\file.php имеет кодировку windows-1251, но PHPStorm открывает его как UTF-8.
Сверху показывает сообщение "The file was loaded in a wrong encoding: 'UTF-8'". Другие файлы открывает нормально, а часть с сообщением "Current file encoding doesn't match UTF-8 from .editorconfig"

При попытки открыть как windows-1251 с помощью "Reload" - открывается все равно в UTF-8.
При попытки открыть как windows-1251 с помощью "Convert" - открывается все равно в UTF-8, только уже со сломанной кириллицей.

Нашёл похожий [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1285673/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2-phpstorm-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B5-windows-1251) но без ответа.

PhpStorm 2022.3.2
Build #PS-223.8617.59, built on January 30, 2023

**Сделал следующее:**
Переименовал проблемный файл. Нашёл файл который открывается корректно в windows-1251, скопировал и заменил (переименовал) на имя проблемного файла. Проблемный файл открыл в другом редакторе, скопировал содержимое и вставил в PHPStorm в проблемный файл. После чего открылся нормально. **НО** до перезагрузки IDE. После перезагрузки опять открывает в UTF-8  с битой кодировкой.

**UPD:**
Уточняю на всякий случай: Рабочая среда Windows7; Файлы проекта лежат на сервере Ubuntu, поднята samba; В Windows монтирован сетевой диск.

**UPD2**
**Сработало следующее:** в файле .editorconfig закомментировал строчку charset в блоке [*].

Comment: в файлах случаем нет BOM?

Comment: И так и так пробовал безрезультатно.

Comment: Удалите .editorconfig, храните все файлы в UTF-8.

Comment: @user7860670 .editorconfig помогает настроить IDE для команды. А с UTF-8 согласен. Но когда есть legacy code в несколько тысяч файлов, приходиться смериться.